# Out of sync state and view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Facing a strange issue with the latest stable releases of Nextjs and React, where state and view updates are out-of-sync.

Example (v1): using `useMemo`

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "apple" },
  { id: 2, name: "orange" },
  { id: 3, name: "mango" }
];

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState(true);

  const sortedItems = useMemo(() => [...(desc ? items : items.reverse())], [
    desc
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setDesc((s) => !s)}>change order</button>
      <br />
      <span>desc: {desc.toString()}</span>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(sortedItems, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example (v2): using `useState`

```
import { useState, useMemo } from "react";

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "apple" },
  { id: 2, name: "orange" },
  { id: 3, name: "mango" }
];

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ desc: true, items });

  function handleSort() {
    setState((s) =>
      s.desc
        ? { desc: false, items: [...items.reverse()] }
        : { desc: true, items: [...items] }
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSort}>change order</button>
      <br />
      <span>desc: {state.desc.toString()}</span>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state.items, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Package versions:

```
"next": "12.1.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

As you can see from the output below, **array elements are not updated on the view front based on the current sort state (in both the examples). Multiple clicks are required to do so**.

Is this a random bug or am I fooling myself!?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/outofsync-next-react-72t1l1) - Contains both code examples

[image: Output]

Comment: I bet changing `[...items.reverse()]` to `[...items].reverse()` will fix this.

Comment: your comment fixes the issue, but I'm confused, whats wrong with `[...items.reverse()]`? `reverse` will mutate the original array and the spread operator will create a new one.  Am I missing some js concept?

Comment: Exactly. But the line underneath is `: { desc: true, items: [...items] }`, which references the original array. Which is now reversed because you mutated it.

Comment: Oh ya. dumb me. I completely missed it. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `.reverse` on a list will mutate it. Then wherever you reference that list again, it will be reversed.

You don't need to copy the items on to state either, you only need the isReversed state.

```
const Comp = () => {
  const [isReversed, setIsReversed] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsReversed(r => !r);

  const list = useMemo(() => isReversed ? [...items].reverse() : items, [isReversed]);

  // use list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `useState` example, separating the states for checking if it has been sorted and state for holding the items would be a great start.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const items = [
  { id: 1, name: "apple" },
  { id: 2, name: "orange" },
  { id: 3, name: "mango" },
];

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [areSorted, setAreSorted] = useState(false);
  const [itemsArr, setItemsArr] = useState(items);

  function handleSort() {
    setAreSorted(!areSorted);
    setItemsArr(itemsArr.reverse());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleSort}>change order</button>
      <br />
      <span>{"Desc : " + areSorted}</span>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(itemsArr, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```